# Filter WPF DataGrid (DataTable) based on values from several TextBoxes MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have been trying to setup filter that would be based on 4 TextBoxes. If first textbox is not empty -> then filter based on that, if first and second textbox is not empty combine filter from these two textboxes etc. I expect my filter to work like this http://www.tablefilter.com/auto-filter.html

As you can see I have tried several variants but I am constantly getting an error provided below. Any suggestions how to get it working?

Here is my code:

```
    public void EnableRowFiltering()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (this.YRNROSearchKey != string.Empty)
        {
            sb.Append($"YRNRO LIKE '%{this.YRNROSearchKey}%' AND ");
        }
        if (this.HAKUNIMISearchKey != string.Empty)
        {
            sb.Append($"HAKUNIMI LIKE '%{this.HAKUNIMISearchKey}%' AND ");
        }
        if (this.GROUPSearchKey != string.Empty)
        {
            sb.Append($"KONSERNI LIKE '%{this.GROUPSearchKey}%' AND ");
        }
        if (this.BUSINESSIDSearchKey != string.Empty)
        {
            sb.Append($"LY LIKE '%{this.BUSINESSIDSearchKey}%' AND ");
        }

        // I have tried also this way without success 
        // this.MainDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = YRNRO + HAKUNIMI + GROUP + BUSINESSID;
        string YRNRO = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.YRNROSearchKey) ? "" : $"YRNRO LIKE '{this.YRNROSearchKey}*'";
        string HAKUNIMI = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.HAKUNIMISearchKey) ? "" : $" AND HAKUNIMI LIKE '{this.HAKUNIMISearchKey}*'";
        string GROUP = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.GROUPSearchKey) ? "" : $" AND KONSERNI LIKE '{this.GROUPSearchKey}*'";
        string BUSINESSID = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.BUSINESSIDSearchKey) ? "" : $" AND LY LIKE '{this.BUSINESSIDSearchKey}*'";

        this.MainDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = sb.ToString();
    }
```

> System.Data.SyntaxErrorException: 'Syntax error: Missing operand after
> 'And' operator.'

This has been working, but I have to provide all values (fill in all TextBoxes) in order to filter:

```
  public void EnableRowFiltering()
  {
    this.MainDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = 
      $"YRNRO LIKE '{this.YRNROSearchKey}*' " + 
      $"OR HAKUNIMI LIKE '{this.HAKUNIMISearchKey}*'" +
      $"OR KONSERNI LIKE '{this.GROUPSearchKey}*'" +
      $"OR LY LIKE '{this.BUSINESSIDSearchKey}*'";
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last solution is by far the shortest of all, so I would prefer it.
You simply have to replace OR with AND (my bad).

```
public void EnableRowFiltering()
{
  this.MainDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = 
    $"YRNRO LIKE '{this.YRNROSearchKey}*'" + 
    $"AND HAKUNIMI LIKE '{this.HAKUNIMISearchKey}*'" +
    $"AND KONSERNI LIKE '{this.GROUPSearchKey}*'" +
    $"AND LY LIKE '{this.BUSINESSIDSearchKey}*'";
}
```

---

The first solution's expression string has a trailing `AND` operator, which leads to the error message. Prefixing each expression (operand) with the operator would fix it.

Note that the leading `%` of the expression must be removed in order to make it a 'starts with' expression. Having a leading `%` and a trailing `%` (wildcard operator) would express a 'contains in'.

Because and empty string variable would result in an expression like `"Column LIKE '%'` and because `${null}` returns `""` (an empty string), you can shorten the code:

```
public void EnableRowFiltering()
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append($"YRNRO LIKE '{this.YRNROSearchKey}%'");
  sb.Append($"AND KONSERNI LIKE '{this.GROUPSearchKey}%'");
  sb.Append($"AND LY LIKE '{this.BUSINESSIDSearchKey}%'");

  this.MainDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = sb.ToString();
}
```

---

The second solution's expression seems to be correct, but somehow the assignment got confused. Assign the filter expression after you have defined it to fix it.

Because and empty string variable would result in an expression like `"Column LIKE '*'` and because `${null}` returns `""` (an empty string), you can shorten the code:

```
public void EnableRowFiltering()
{ 
  string YRNRO = $"YRNRO LIKE '{this.YRNROSearchKey}*'";
  string HAKUNIMI = $" AND HAKUNIMI LIKE '{this.HAKUNIMISearchKey}*'";
  string GROUP = $" AND KONSERNI LIKE '{this.GROUPSearchKey}*'";
  string BUSINESSID = $" AND LY LIKE '{this.BUSINESSIDSearchKey}*'";

  this.MainDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = YRNRO + HAKUNIMI + GROUP + BUSINESSID;
}
```

After fixing and improving all three solutions, they all were reduced to basically the same solution.

Comment: Thank you again! First solution looks neat but it will fail if one of Textbox is empty? With AND statement none of provided solutions work. However if I replace all AND to OR in your first solution filter works, but in this case all TextBoxes should not be empty. So I have to input some data to all of them.

Comment: I have tested it and it works exactly like in your example. First TextBox input filters. Second input filters the results of the previous filter and so on. It works when all TextBox are empty or only one is empty. This leads to the assumption that something else is wrong

Comment: Do the text boxes have any initial value? Can you please show the bindings from TextBox to view model?

Comment: Consider both logical operators and their produced results: AND will act like a multi stage or stacked sieve. First expression will produce a result. Second expression will produce a result based on the previous result set. When using OR each filter operates like multiple parallel sieves on the original data set. First expression produces a result. Second expression adds its result based on the original set to the the result set of the first expression. From your example it looks like you wanted the stacked sieve (logical AND).

Comment: Oh, I missed it again! I have messed up the bindings so two of them were connected vice versa. It works now! Thank you again! Now I would like to filter while typing to TextBox without switching to next TextBox in order to update filter. I probably need to ask another question or follow comment Kryzstof's comment?

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't recommend Rx in this scenario. Simply configure the data binding and set `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`. The value is set to`LostFocus`by default (for the TextBox).

Answer (score 1):

I would go with ReactiveExtensions (especially those from [RxUI](https://www.reactiveui.net/)):

```
// written without IDE
var text1 = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.YRNROSearchKey).Select(x => {
       if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
          return null;
       return $"YRNRO LIKE '%{x}%";
     }); // get observable to monitor changes
var text2 = ...

var filterObservable = Observable.CombineLatest(
                new []{text1, text2, text3} , 
                    (textParts) => {
                         return string.Join(" AND ",  textParts.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)));
                    }
             )
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(80));

filterObservable.ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(f => this.MainDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = f);
```

I really like Rx so that is how I would do it - maybe you can use as a template and solve the change notification in some other manner, but constructing the filter should work.

RxUI also comes with DyanmicData - great lib for data manipulation, it's basically observable LINQ

Comment: Quite an overkill in order to concat 4 strings.

Comment: it depends, if you want the filter to change while the user types instead of when the button is pressed, it's quite cool. You can just take the `string.Join` part

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek What is `WhenAnyValue` - does not compile? This is missing one bracket `.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(80)))` in the end

Comment: Also these can be added in order somebody would be wondering the same `using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;`

Comment: `this.WhenAnyValue` is extension method from RxUI for objects implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, where `this` in that case is a view model

Comment: I assumed that `YRNROSearchKey` and other are bindable properties of a view model bound to text boxes

Comment: also, most of the code is for autoupdate - only the `string.Join` is for concat

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle the `AND` operator. You can't add it any time, it depends how many conditions (filters) are set.

Supposing to defining a variable named `int counter` set equal to zero at the start-time and increased every time a filter is set and decreased any time a filter is cleaned, your code should be changed into this:

```
public void EnableRowFiltering()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        var logicalOperator = counter > 0 ? " AND " : string.Empty;

        if (YRNROSearchKey != string.Empty)
        {
            logicalOperator = counter++ > 0 ? " AND " : string.Empty;
            sb.Append($"{logicalOperator}YRNRO LIKE '%{YRNROSearchKey}%'");
        }
        if (HAKUNIMISearchKey != string.Empty)
        {
            logicalOperator = counter++ > 0 ? " AND " : string.Empty;
            sb.Append($"{logicalOperator}HAKUNIMI LIKE '%{HAKUNIMISearchKey}%'");
        }
        if (GROUPSearchKey != string.Empty)
        {
            logicalOperator = counter++ > 0 ? " AND " : string.Empty;
            sb.Append($"{logicalOperator}KONSERNI LIKE '%{GROUPSearchKey}%'");
        }
        if (BUSINESSIDSearchKey != string.Empty)
        {
            logicalOperator = counter++ > 0 ? " AND " : string.Empty;
            sb.Append($"{logicalOperator}LY LIKE '%{BUSINESSIDSearchKey}%'");
        }

        this.MainDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = sb.ToString();
    }
```